# Need help in adding Foreign key using django models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Okay so I don't know how to frame this.
I have two models Employee and Customer. I am storing the Employee as foreign key in Customer model under emp_id. The epm_id stores the primary key of the employee who admits the customer. I am not sure how to do this in django.
Here are my models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phoneno = models.IntegerField()
    emailid = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    children = models.IntegerField()
    adults = models.IntegerField()
    roomtype = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    aadharno = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    daysstayed = models.IntegerField()
    date_visited = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True) 

class Employee(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phoneno = models.IntegerField()
    emailid = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    aadharno = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    datejoined = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

I need some help here.

Comment: `emp_id` can be named as `emp`, it will access instance of `Employee`.

What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could suggest is that you create the models as follows:

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    SEX = [
       ('male', 'Male'),
       ('female', 'Female'),
       ('not_to_say', 'Rather not to say')
    ]
    
    class BaseModel(models.Model):
        age = models.IntegerField()
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SEX)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        aadhar_no = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    
    class Employee(BaseModel):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee_user')
        salary = models.IntegerField()
        designation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        
   class Customer(BaseModel):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer_user')
        childrens = models.IntegerField()
        adults = models.IntegerField()
        room_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        days_stayed = models.IntegerField()
        date_visited = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, relted_name='serving_employee')
```

You can access `password`, `date_joined`, `first_name`, `last_name` & `email` of `employee` from `Employee.user`, and `first_name`, `last_name` & `email` of `customer` from `Customer.user`.

I hope this solves your problem.